# Type '{ children: string; download: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &amp; { downloadPageLink: any; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-props, react-proptypes

I'm working on a simple React application, Where you can share your files. So when I upload the file it goes back to the database and creates a secure_Url and displays it in the front-end. That is `downloadPageLink`. I don't know why it's throwing this error when I import my file to `index.tsx`

this is my **`index.tsx`**

```
import DropZoneComponent from "@components/DropZoneComponent";
import {useState} from "react";
import RenderFile from "@components/RenderFile";
import axios from "axios";
import DownloadFile from "../components/DownloadFile";

export default function Home() {
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null)
    const [id, setId] = useState(null)
    const [downloadPageLink, setDownloadPageLink] = useState()
    const [uploadState, setUploadState] = useState<"Uploading" | "Upload Failed" | "Uploaded" | "Upload">("Upload")

    const handleUpload = async () => {
        if (uploadState === "Uploading") return;
        setUploadState("Uploading")

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("myFile", file)
        try {
            const {data} = await axios({
                method: "POST",
                data: formData,
                url: "api/files/upload",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                }
            });
            setDownloadPageLink(data.downloadPageLink);
            setId(data.id);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response.data)
            setUploadState("Upload Failed")
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <h1 className="my-4 text-2xl font-weight-medium font-body tracking-wide">Got a file? Lezz share it!</h1>
            <div className="w-96 h-auto flex flex-col items-center bg-gray-800 shadow-xl rounded-xl justify-center">
                {!downloadPageLink && <DropZoneComponent setFile={setFile}/>}
                {file &&
                <RenderFile file={{
                    format: file.type.split("/")[1],
                    name: file.name,
                    sizeInByte: file.size,
                }}
                />
                }
                <button className="w-36 bg-gray-900 rounded-md h-10 mb-6 focus:outline-none font-body tracking-wider transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-0 hover:scale-110 "
                        onClick={handleUpload}>{uploadState}</button>
                {
                    downloadPageLink &&
                    <DownloadFile download={downloadPageLink} >
                        Email form
                    </DownloadFile>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here's my **`DownloadFile.tsx`**

```
 const DownloadFile = ({downloadPageLink}) => {
    return (
        <div className="p-1">
            <h1 className="my-2 text-lg font-medium font-body">
                Yo
            </h1>
            <div className="flex space-x-3">
                <span className="break-all">{downloadPageLink}</span>
                <img src="/images/copy.png" alt="" className="w-8 h-8 object-contain cursor-pointer"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

 export default DownloadFile
```

My **`_app.tsx`**

```
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import "../../styles/globals.css";
import axios from "axios";


axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
      <div className="grid h-screen font-serif text-white bg-gray-900 place-items-center">
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
  )
}

export default MyApp;
```

My **`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "save-walter-x",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "next": "10.1.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/jit": "^0.1.18",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8.2.9",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
}
```

I'm experiencing this complication in `index.tsx` when I'm importing the `DownloadFile.tsx` to `index.tsx`

What am I doing wrong and why typescript is behaving acting weird? I'm new to this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `DownloadFile` Component, you have explicitly mentioned the only expected props as `downloadPageLink`. There are two mistakes.

1. In `index.tsx`, you are sending the prop as `download`. It should have been `downloadPageLink`like the below snippet.

```
<DownloadFile downloadPageLink={downloadPageLink} >
                        Email form
                    </DownloadFile>
```

2. You are not using the children in the `DownloadFile` component. Either remove the children or use the children in `DownloadFile` component.
   Instead of this

```
<DownloadFile downloadPageLink={downloadPageLink} >
                        Email form
                    </DownloadFile>
```

it should be like this

```
<DownloadFile downloadPageLink={downloadPageLink} />
```

Answer (score 1):

on `index.ts` you are using

```
<DownloadFile download={downloadPageLink} >
```

The name of the `prop` for `DownloadFile` is called **download**

The definition of DownloadFile has the parameter `const DownloadFile = ({downloadPageLink})` (not download)

I particularly use props as a parameter because you could have more than one, or you can split them using {}, but you need to use the same name

Then the code using props is

```
const DownloadFile = (props) => {
..
                <span className="break-all">{props.download}</span>
```

or you could leave it the same as before

```
const DownloadFile = ({download}) => {
    ..
                    <span className="break-all">{download}</span>
```

Comment: It worked thank you! Duly noted, I'll follow this method when I use props